# エラーが出てないけど、insertできていない(fuelphp)

Tags: php, mysql, fuelphp

fuelphpでmysqlにレコードをinsertしたいのですができません。
詳細は下記です。
エラーログも出ていないのでプログラミング初心者の私は、
何が起きているのか迷宮入り状態です。
お手数おかけしますが、ご回答頂けると幸いです。
宜しくお願いします。

friend2.php(/Users/■■■■/Desktop/fuelphp/fuel/app/classes/controller)
class Controller_Friend2でクラスを定義して、
public function メソッドでinsertする内容を記入し、
execute();でメソッドの内容を実行するようにコードが作れてると思ってますが、
不備があればご教示願います。

```
<?php

namespace App\Classes;

use Friend2;

class Controller_Friend2  {

    public function action_insert() {

    DB::insert('friend')->set(array(
        'id' => '777',
        'name' => '梅宮辰夫',
        'age' => '71',
        'sex' => '男',
    ))->execute();
         }
}
?>
```

localhost/friend2.php(エラーも何も表示されていない)
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

id 777,name 梅宮辰夫,age 71,sex 男が追加されていない

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

db.php(/Users/■■■■/Desktop/fuelphp/fuel/app/config)

```
<?php
return array(
    'default' => array(
        'type'        => 'mysqli',
        'connection'  => array(
            'persistent' => false,
        ),
        'identifier'   => '`',
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'charset'      => 'utf8',
        'collation'    => false,
        'enable_cache' => true,
        'profiling'    => false,
        'readonly'     => false,
    ),
);
```

db.php(/Users/■■■■/Desktop/fuelphp/fuel/app/config/development)

```
<?php
return array(
  'default' => array(
    'connection'  => array(
        'dsn'    => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=personal',
        'port'     => '3306',
        'username'   => 'root',
        'password'   => 'root',
       ),
        'profiling' => true,
    ),
);
```

Comment: insert に成功するとexecuteの返り値として、insertされたIDのリストと、insertされた レコード数を含む配列が返却されるはずですが、その返り値はどうなっていますか？[INSERT文](http://fuelphp.jp/docs/1.6/classes/database/usage.html#inserting)

Comment: returnを使って、public function action_insert()の内容を表示させるイメージでしょうか？

Comment: もっともシンプルにやるならば　[fuelのdebugクラス](http://press.nekoget.com/fuelphp_doc/classes/debug.html)を利用してみてはいかがでしょうか？ブラウザに表示することも可能です。

Answer (score 1):

このコードでは、friend2.phpはクラスを定義しているだけで処理を何も実行していません。

```
$controller = new Controller_Friend2();
$controller->action_insert();
```

をファイル内のクラス宣言後に追加してみてください。